# Work done by a ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, work, ideal-gas

Say you have a big piston and it contains  a ideal gas. say the gas expands ( we heated it). so, is the work done by the gas equal to the work done on the surrounding or the work done by the gas the negative of the work by the surroundings?

Comment: Welcome to SE. The answer is undefined because you have to specify the exact transformation. Is the transformation quasistatic? Is there friction in the syringe? Is the gas heated from the inside (allowing for an adiabatic process) or is the heat received through its boundaries? $\delta W$, being a non-exact differential, depends on these details.

Comment: The work done by the gas is equal to the work done on the surroundings.

Comment: @ChetMiller I think the OP is asking if the surroundings is doing negative work.

Comment: @bob d I think the answer that the op question is “both “

Comment: @ChetMiller That's exactly the answer I had considered.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but won’t the work done on the surroundings be equal to the negative of the work done by the surroundings?